# Regex: Invalid preceding regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

Trying to filter the following:

```
Jul 13 20:51:28 dnsmasq[26211]: query[A] r5---sn-q4fl6ne7.googlevideo.com
Jul 13 20:51:28 dnsmasq[26211]: forwarded r5---sn-q4fl6ne7.googlevideo.com
Jul 13 20:51:29 dnsmasq[26211]: reply r5---sn-q4fl6ne7.googlevideo.com
```

I am using the following:

```
cat /var/log/pihole.log | grep -o ".*\.googlevideo\.com" | sed -e 's/[a-zA-z]{3}[[:space:]][1-9]{2}[[:space:]]([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))[[:space:]][^:]*.{8}//'
```

I keep getting:

```
Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Am I doing this incorrectly? I was using https://regex101.com/ to build my regex.

Comment: sed regex is quite different from PCRE type regex... `\d` is not supported... there are no lookarounds.. no unnamed capture group support and lot many other things.. it would help if you gave complete input sample, describe what you need to do and add expected output for sample... you can also try to replace `sed -e` with `perl -pe`

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Do you **really** need tthe whole line `cat /var/log/pihole.log | grep -o ".*\.googlevideo\.com" | sed -e 's/[a-zA-z]{3}[[:space:]][1-9]{2}[[:space:]]([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))[[:space:]][^:]*.{8}//'` to produce that error message or could you have put a little effort into identifying the smallest part of that command line that is actually producing the error message? Doing that is always a good idea for any problem and had you don't that you'd probably have solved the problem for yourself. See [ask] and pay particular attention to the word "Minimal" in [mcve].

Comment: P.S. as you just discovered using online regexp tools to create/verify regexps for command-line tools is useless since every command-line tool supports different regexp flavors and has its own additional caveats.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it.

I was able to do it with

```
cut -d" " -f6
```

Comment: you can also use `awk '{print $NF}'` to print last field in space delimited input

Comment: and you can use single command instead of three... `awk '/\.googlevideo\.com/{print $NF}' /var/log/pihole.log`